# Any example to show "Numbered Scopes" concept?

Tags: powershell, scope

In PowerShell, `help about_Scopes` shows there's several different scopes defines, one of them is called "Numbered Scopes". I searched google but didn't find a good example on it. Could anyone provide one to show the concept of how "Numbered Scopes" works?

I also have the same question on "Private" scope. Any examples?

Comment: `&{$a=1;&{$a=2;&{$a=3;&{gv a -Scope 3}}}}`, `&{$a=1;&{$private:a=2;&{$a}}}`.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more on the `private` modifier: it restricts an object to the current scope, meaning that the object is not available in child scopes. Example: if you define two variables `$a` and `$private:b` in a function `f1()` and then call another function `f2()` from within `f1` only `$a` will be available in `f2`.